# Why does inotifywait exit after any event, not just the events it's "watching for"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example...

```
inotifywait --event modify ./my-file | doSomething
```

...will wait until any event happens to `my-file`, at which time it will exit. If the event was not the `modify` event, then there is no output and the exit code is zero.

This was very confusing, and resulted in us needing to add a loop:

```
while true; do
    local eventInfo=$(inotifywait --event modify ./my-file)

    if [[ "${eventInfo}" != '' ]]; then
       doSomething ${eventInfo}
       break
    fi

    # if we get here, then some other event we don't care about happened -- why??
done
```

This seems counter intuitive -- why is it this way and is there any documentation stating that the `--event` flag will not stop `inotifywait` from exiting when a non-watched event occurs?

---

**Reproduction**

In Terminal 1, create and open a test file (`test`) in an editor.

In Terminal 2, run:

```shell
inotifywait -q --event modify ./test | cat
```

In Terminal 1, modify and save the file. Note that Terminal 2 outputs `./test MODIFY` and exists -- good.

Run the same command again in Terminal 2.

In Terminal 1, exit the editor and delete the file (`test`).

In Terminal 2, note that `inotifywait` has exited, with no output -- it exited due to the `DELETE` event, which it was not configured to "care about".

Comment: I know that using a loop like this causes a race condition: you will miss events. Beside, I can't reproduce your problem: if I create my-file and run your command, then reading my-file doesn't stop inotifywait despite an open an access and a close event. Maybe something uncommon is also used? A special filesystem maybe?

Comment: Have you read `man 1 inotifywait`? There is `--monitor` option described there.

Comment: I don't think we can use the `--monitor` option because we only care about the first modify or delete event, after which, we run some function. So we do want `inotifywait` to quit after the first event _of the event types we care about_.

Comment: @A.B -- added reproduction steps so you can see how this is happening on your own. I've tested this in RHEL and Manjaro and get the same result.

Comment: Ok. with the new information that the file is deleted, then I can reproduce it. man page tells "delete_self [...]  After this event the file or directory is no longer being watched. Note that  this event can occur even if it is not explicitly being listened for."

Comment: @A.B hmm, I didn't notice that in the docs. Thanks for pointing it out.